# How to inverse a function that has a range

Tags: calculus, functions, inverse-function

I'm given 
$$ k(x)=\begin{cases} -5x+6,& x<4\\-4x+2,&x\ge 4\:\end{cases} $$
And I have to find $k^{-1}(x)$.

I found inverse of the both functions
$$
-\frac{x-2}{4}
$$
$$
-\frac{x-6}{5}
$$

But what will their range be?

Comment: Plugging in $4$ in $-4x+2$ you get $-14$,now since the function is decreasing the range of the function is $(-\infty,-14]$ and the second is $(-14,\infty)$

Comment: @kingW3 you have provided the range of the original function $k(x)$. Isn't the OP asking for the range of the inverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the change of its form at $k=4$, the function $k(x)$ is monotone decreasing on $\mathbb R$ and continuous at $x=4$. Hence $$k^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}-\dfrac{x-2}{4}, & x\le -14 \\ -\dfrac{x-6}{5}, & x>-14\end{cases}$$ where $-14=k(4)$.

Answer (score 1):

So good job on finding your inverses:

$$
-\frac{x-2}{4}
$$
$$
-\frac{x-6}{5}
$$

Recall that the definition of a function maps $x$ values to $y$ values, or $k(x)$. Therefore, the inverse of a function $k(x)$ maps the $y$ values to the $x$ values.

So we must find our range of $x$ values:

Since $k(4) = -14$, $k^{-1}(-14) = 4$

So we have:

$$k^{-1}(x)=\begin{cases}-\dfrac{x-2}{4}, & x\le -14 \\ -\dfrac{x-6}{5}, & x>-14\end{cases}$$

Therefore, if we want the range of these inverse functions, we simply look at the domain of our original function $k(x)$.

Therefore, the range of the inverse functions are $(-\infty, 4)$ & $(4, \infty)$, respectively.